Pass string with single quote and special characters to the Uri field inside the Send Http Request inside Power Automate flow
I have this "Send Http Request to SharePoint" action inside my child flow, to check if there is a Term equals the FolderName parameter, as follow:-

Now the main issue is with the highlighted parameter.
Where the value of the highlighted parameter can have values such as: -
First-Example) Test Test2
Second-Example) Test ' Test
Third-Example) Test # Test
Now i were passing the parameters as-is variables('FolderName') >> which will work for the first-Example only.
So  i did this replace to be able to pass single quote  replace(variables('FolderNameWithoutUnAllowedChars'),'''','''''') >> which will work for the first-example & second-example only
Also if i only do this encodeUriComponent(variables('FolderNameWithoutUnAllowedChars')) without the replace >> this will work for First-example & Third-example only
So i did this to be able to pass single quote and special charecter such as "#" encodeUriComponent(replace(variables('FolderNameWithoutUnAllowedChars'),'''',''''''))  >> which work for all values..
My question is if i am ding things correctly ? is it normal to do replace() & encodeUriComponent() to pass parameters inside the Uri field? or there is a more straight forward approach?
Thanks

Yes, this is a correct approach to solve these issues.
